# How to print multi-line segment starting with a particular string with awk

Tags: awk

I am using the ldapsearch command as follows where my output string starts with specific string at the begning with "dn" where i want only lines which has another line associated with this, saying that i don't  want any line starting with "dn" with single line output containing space just after.

```
bash-4.1$ ldapsearch -h kts77 -LLL -xxx -b "ou=networks,ou=corp,ou=services,o=swift.com" '(&(cn=*noida*))' dn krvNetworkServiceKVP 

dn: ipnetworknumber=192.168.1, ou=networks,ou=corp,ou=services,o=swift.com

dn: ipnetworknumber=192.168.2, ou=networks,ou=corp,ou=services,o=swift.
 com

dn: ipnetworknumber=172.23.48, ou=networks,ou=corp,ou=services,o=swift.com
krvNetworkServiceKVP: auto_master_lnx=auto_master_lnx_noida
krvNetworkServiceKVP: SyslogServer=ralph-noida.swift.com
krvNetworkServiceKVP: adsite=India
krvNetworkServiceKVP: cupsserver=vlno-noidacups
krvNetworkServiceKVP: dnsserver_1=192.168.1.100
krvNetworkServiceKVP: dnsserver_2=192.168.2.100
```

Desired output should only be:

```
dn: ipnetworknumber=172.23.48, ou=networks,ou=corp,ou=services,o=swift.com
krvNetworkServiceKVP: auto_master_lnx=auto_master_lnx_noida
krvNetworkServiceKVP: SyslogServer=ralph-noida.swift.com
krvNetworkServiceKVP: adsite=India
krvNetworkServiceKVP: cupsserver=vlno-noidacups
krvNetworkServiceKVP: dnsserver_1=192.168.1.100
krvNetworkServiceKVP: dnsserver_2=192.168.2.100
```

Comment: post the desired output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, i just updated the question with desired output.

Comment: For the 2nd `dn` output block - is the `com` REALLY on a second line or is that a typo? If the latter then fix it.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's the expected One.

Comment: Not 100% sure what that means but if your posted expected output is not correct then just [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: @EdMorton, my bad.. I just checked agian and that's the reall output for some of the queries from the command i given in the question.. `com` is coming in second line.

Comment: Then how can we distinguish between multi-line output like that vs the multi-line output you want to print? Your requirement of `i don't want any line starting with "dn" with single line output containing space just after.` is now wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton, your answer is correct only , i ran the complete search some of the line ending with `com` in second line but there are some output which i need to remove is only line which end in single line starting with `dn` and thats i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably all you need, assuming your posted expected output has a typo that's making the 2nd output record appear to be on 2 lines:

```
ldapsearch ... | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' 'NF>1'
```

Given your comments maybe one of these is what you need:

```
ldapsearch ... | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$2!~/^ /'
```

or

```
ldapsearch ... | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$2~/^krvNetworkServiceKVP/'
```

or.... Basically you need to tell us what the criteria is for printing lines.

Comment: It would be great if you can add details about the switches

Comment: you are correct :) .. i'll look on that , appreciate your time!